Accessing the packet data including the IP header from a UDP packet in C#
The title is kind of self explanatory, I'd like to access the IP header from all UDP packet I'm receiving. Why? There are some flags I'd like to use to be able to de-fragment UDP packets and merge them back together, such as the MF flag (more fragments).
If there is a better way to merge UDP packets together, let me know, or if there's a way to access a packet's IP header without requiring administrative permissions, also let me know, or if I'm totally wrong on what I'm saying, let me know too.
What I've tried

Using a raw socket, had to use admin permissions, or flat out just crashed

What I didn't want to try

Pcap.Net, it's windows only as far as I know.


Combining IP level fragments is already done by the OS kernel, i.e. your application will already get the full UDP datagrams without IP fragmentation. So I can see no need to do what you want. But note that UDP datagrams can still be lost, duplicated, reordered etc, i.e. you cannot just combine a sequence of UDP datagrams to a stream like TCP provides.

@SteffenUllrich oh, so you mean packets that are too big get fragmented and automatically re-assembled by the OS?

Yes, the OS takes care of reassembly. Note though that UDP datagrams are still limited to max 64k in size, fragmentation or not. And the larger a datagram is the more it needs to be fragmented and the more likely is that it gets lost (since only one fragment need to be lost - there is no retransmission).

Well then there'd never be a case where my packets would be bigger than 64K, thanks for letting me know, since some people told me otherwise.

packet is not the same as datagram. A packet is the what gets transmitted on the wire and the size is limited by link layer standards. A datagram is limited by transport layer standards (UDP). For transport a datagram might be fragmented into several packets - but the datagram limit of 64k is a transport layer property.

Turns out the OS does it for me, the actual max size is 64K, but if you need packets that long, you'd most likely need to rethink your whole system.
Thanks for Steffen for letting me know, some people told me otherwise, and got me confused, so I hope this self-answer gets at least one less person confused.
